# Return all possible sorted lists when no tie-breaker is given

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Suppose we have a list of tuples, say:

`my_list = [(1, 100), (2, 100), (1, 101)]`

Now we can sort this list in python based on the second element of each tuple using the following line of code:

`sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[1])`

This gives us a single sorted list:

`[(1, 100), (2, 100), (1, 101)]`

The first and the second elements in this list have the same value of the key (second element of tuple) that we sorted the list according to it.

But what if we actually wanted to get all possible sortings of the list, regardless of any tie-breaking rule. More precisely, I am looking for a function that produces the following result:

`get_all_sorts(my_list)`

`# Result:`

`[[(1, 100), (2, 100), (1, 101)], [(2, 100), (1, 100), (1, 101)]]`

Note that I am not simply looking for the permutations of the list, but the permutations that are also sorted. I know I can generate all permutations and pick the sorted ones but that is very time-consuming. Any better solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Very long: `[list(chain.from_iterable(p)) for p in product(*[permutations(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(...), key=lambda x: x[1])])]`, where `chain`, `product`, `permutations` and `groupby` come from `itertools`.

Comment: Thanks @MechanicPig. But I tried it and it didn't work. It returns a list of only one list.

Comment: On my machine, python 3.9.13, 3.10.9, and 3.11.1 all give correct result. What version of python do you use?